# React and Swiper -- Items not fully rendering in slides

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backend, swiper.js

I'm using [this package](http://kidjp85.github.io/react-id-swiper/) to generate a swiper of dynamic slides with content from an external API. I can get the content to generate outside of the swiper no problem, but once it needs to render within the swiper, I can see the first item, but can't use the arrows to navigate to the different slides (even though I can sort of swipe through and see that the other items have rendered. How can I fix this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import '../styles/vendor/swiper/swiper.min.css';
import Swiper from 'react-id-swiper';

export default class PortfolioSwiperAll extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      portfolio_items: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let portfolioURL = "[api endpoint hidden]";
    fetch(portfolioURL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          portfolio_items: res
        })
      })
    }

  render() {
    const params = {
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
      }
    }

    let portfolio_items = this.state.portfolio_items.map((portfolio_item, index) => {
      return <div key={index}>
      <p><strong>Title:</strong> {portfolio_item.title.rendered}</p>
      </div>
    });

    return(
      <div className="portfolio-container">
      <h2>Portfolio</h2>
      <Swiper {...params}>
        {portfolio_items}
        </Swiper>

        {/* testing to see that it does render */}
        <h3>actual items</h3>
        {portfolio_items}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be DOM mounting issue. Just an idea, but you could try conditionally render Swiper when you have items available. `{portfolio_items.length > 0 && <Swiper {...params}>{portfolio_items} </Swiper>
} `